# How to grep a string in bash with letters out of order?

Tags: string, bash, gnu-coreutils, acronym

I have a task to do which is to find some strings (acronyms) that repeat in some specific text file.

Here follows a sample:

```sh
...
the
the
het
het
het
teh
teh
teh
teh
...
```

In the first step, I can count how many times each one of that appears with this command:

```sh
cat text_file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr
```

And the output is something like this:

```sh
2 the
3 het
4 teh
```

But I need also to "count/sum" these three outputs because they are using the same three characters but in a different order.

Can you guys please give me some help about this?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I think you mean "anagram" instead of "acronym"

Comment: What does `sort -g` do? I usually use `sort -n` for sorting by count prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for splitting a string into chars given a null FS and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,chars,"")
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
    key = ""
    for (i in chars) {
        key = key chars[i]
    }
    cnt[key]++
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (key in cnt) {
        print key, cnt[key]
    }
}

$ cat file
the
het
teh
foobar
fobar
oofrab

$ awk -f tst.awk file
abfoor 2
abfor 1
eht 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With this script I have what I was looking for. Many thanks! =)